# kafka + how to set specific retention byets for specific topic as permamnet

Tags: apache-kafka

we want to set for specific topic the retention bytes

while all other topics will get the retention bytes from the kafka configuration file - `server.properties`

so we set the retention bytes to `1057600` for `Test_topic` topic

```
kafka-topics --zookeeper localhost:2181 --alter --topic  Test_topic --config retention.bytes=1057600
```

the problem is when we restart the kafka confluent service then restart will erase the setting of `retention.bytes=1057600`to other default values that defined in `server.properties`

the question is - how to set specific retention bytes for specific topic that will set for permanent even after Kafka service restart

similar questions - https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/How-to-define-topic-retention-with-kafka/td-p/222671

Comment: Not clear how you have installed Kafka/Confluent Platform or started it, or how data is persisted. Please add that information

Comment: the kafka confluent is old cluster with version 0.1 , - what you mean - "started it" , the goal is to set retention bytes for some topics while all other topics will get the retention bytes from default configuration as defined in server.properties

Comment: You mean `0.10`? And how do you install Kafka? Like `systemctl start confluent-kafka`, as it exists today if you installed using `yum`, or `docker run` or `kubectl apply kafka.yml` or are you using Cloudera Manager/Ambari, etc... This information is needed to determine where/how data would be stored and kept. Otherwise, I suggest you upgrade to at least 1.0 or preferrably 2.x

Comment: yes I mean 0.10 - we have old prod cluster with 3 nodes

Comment: this isnt docker kafka , we install it according tio confluent procedure

Comment: so based on this info can you please advice about my posts?

Comment: Please link to this "confluent procedure. Please create a [mcve] with your installation steps